# solving for $y$ in $0.95^2 = \frac{\tanh(2 \pi y)}{2 \pi y}$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a rather basic question, but I want to find the ratio between a given water height (H) and wavelength ($\lambda$) for a maximum error of 5% between the ratio of the wave speed ($c$) and the long wave speed ($c_\ell$).

In other words:

let $\frac{H}{\lambda} = y$ and $\frac{c}{c_l} = 0.95$ for the equation:

$$0.95 = \sqrt{\frac{\tanh(2 \pi y)}{2 \pi y}}$$

and I want to solve for $y$. I tried a couple of things including using an $\operatorname{arctanh}(x)$ identity, but it seemed really clumsy and it got me nowhere.

Comment: One way: Square both sides, multiply by denominator and expand a few terms of the series to get a good enough approximation.

Comment: There is no analytical solution, I guess. Numerical methods would be required. I shall be back within 12 hours and I shall put an answer.

Comment: Thank for your comments. Is it a silly question if I asked why doesn't it have an analytical solution? I mean, did someone used the trial and error method or is that a consensus that that kind of solution is not analytical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in an early comment, such an equation $$k = \frac{\tanh(2 \pi y)}{2 \pi y}$$ does not show analytical solution and numerical methods should be used; the simplest would be Newton which for the specific value would rather quickly converge to solution.

Just as Yves Daoust answered, setting $x=2\pi y$ we can build approximations using Taylor series $$\frac{\tanh(x)}x=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{2 x^4}{15}-\frac{17 x^6}{315}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ which is very interesting since containing only even powers of $x$.

So, depending on the number of used terms, we just have to solve a linear, a quadratic or a cubic equation in $x^2$. Let me note $x_{(n)}^2$ the solution; we then have $$x_{(1)}^2=3(1-k)$$ $$x_{(2)}^2=\frac{1}{4} \left(5- \sqrt{120 k-95}\right)$$ I do not provide the expression for $x_{(3)}^2$; it is too long to write down.

Using $k=0.95^2=0.9025$, the above would then lead to $x_{(1)}\approx 0.540833$, $x_{(2)}\approx 0.581611, $$x_{(3)}\approx 0.574723$ the exact solution, as given by Newton method, being $\approx 0.575490$.

However, we can do better if, instead of Taylor series, we use Padé approximants. They would be $$\frac{\tanh(x)}x\approx \frac{\frac{x^2}{15}+1}{\frac{2 x^2}{5}+1}\implies x^2=\frac{15 (1-k)}{6 k-1}$$ $$\frac{\tanh(x)}x\approx \frac{\frac{x^4}{945}+\frac{x^2}{9}+1}{\frac{x^4}{63}+\frac{4 x^2}{9}+1}\implies x^2=\frac{3 \left(\sqrt{35} \sqrt{380 k^2-88 k+23}-140 k+35\right)}{2 (15 k-1)}$$ These would respectively lead to $x\approx0.575549$ and   $x\approx 0.575490$ (this last one being the "exact" solution, obtained at the price of a quadratic equation in $x^2$).

Answer (score 1):

For a first approximation, use the Taylor development up to fourth degree,

$$0.9025=\frac{\tanh(x)}x\approx1-\frac{x^2}3+\frac{2x^4}{15}.$$

Then solving the quadratic and the biquadratic equation,

$$y\approx 0.086076\cdots,\\y\approx0.092566\cdots$$

are two approximations, by excess and by default.

A few steps by the secant method should give a decent value.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of solving that analytically unfortunately. You're best bet is to use something like Wolfram Alpha - I've done it for you [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+0+%3D+tanh(2*pi*y)%2F(2*pi*y)+-+0.95%5E2)